# Converting a YouTube embed link to a regular link in Python

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python, C# is what I usually code in.

I have the following:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/FjHGZj2IjBk?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjHGZj2IjBk
```

I wrote a basic function, and it works, but is it done in the best, most readable way?

```
embed_links = [
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/NL5ZuWmrisA?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/gnZImHvA0ME?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/FjHGZj2IjBk?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0"
]

def convert_to_regular_youtube_link(embed_link):
    embed_link_split = embed_link.split('/')

    video_id_with_params = embed_link_split[4]

    head, sep, tail = video_id_with_params.partition('?')

    video_id = head

    final_youtube_link = f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}'

    return final_youtube_link


for link in embed_links:
    print(convert_to_regular_youtube_link(link))
```

Comment: @rak1507 while that is in some regards the best way to do it, OP also half-asked for a readable way, and that immediately disqualifies any regex-based approach

Comment: @Hobbamok Regex is great at parsing simple grammars. I'm always a fan when parser libraries support regex because then the grammars can be more readable. A blanket statement like "regex is unreadable" is just untrue. Even looking at the specifics of the top answer, the regex solution isn't unreadable.

Comment: @Peilonrayz were my comments deleted or something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The functional approach to your problem is a good start. But relying on splitting and indexing strings, more specifially URLs and accessing their parts by index may be error-prone.

## Use standard library tools to parse URLs

There are `urrlib.parse` and `pathlib` providing you with functions to parse and manipulate URLs and paths.

## Naming

The parameter name `embed_link` may be improved upon. It is rather a URL, so why not just call it that. Also consider capitalizing global constants.

## Use `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard

... so that your script does not run, if one only wants to import the function.

## Use docstrings

... to document your functions. Briefly explain what they are doing.

## Type hinting

You may (or may not) use type hints to clarify to the user what types of parameters your function expects and what it returns.

## Suggested change:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse


EMBED_URLS = [
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/NL5ZuWmrisA?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/gnZImHvA0ME?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0",
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/FjHGZj2IjBk?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0"
]


def convert_to_watch_url(embed_url: str) -> str:
    """Convert a YouTube embed URL into a watch URL."""

    scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse(embed_url)
    video_id, path = Path(path).stem, '/watch'
    return urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, params, f'v={video_id}', fragment))


def main() -> None:
    """Convert and print the test URLs."""

    for embed_url in EMBED_URLS:
        print(convert_to_watch_url(embed_url))
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you @RichardNeumann, that's some great feedback! Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, but maybe wait for more reviews, before you accept any answer.

Comment: If you add a type hint of `-> None` then static analysis tools like mypy will typecheck it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the most readable code to me would be pattern matching, i.e. using regex, and ensuring a docstring. Dealing with splits and indices is always a bother to read (it would then be better if you did tuple unpacking into named variables), and you don't need any real flexibility here anyway so it would be a very simple operation. You don't really need anything else than:

```py
import re

def convert_to_watch_url(url: str) -> str:
    """Converts youtube embed-url to watch-url
    
    >>> convert_to_watch_url("https://www.youtube.com/embed/FjHGZj2IjBk?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0")
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjHGZj2IjBk'

    """
    pattern = r"^.*/embed/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\?controls.*$"
    repl = r"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\1"
    return re.sub(pattern, repl, url)
```

Then I'd probably turn it into a script that accepts arguments:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Small script to convert YouTube embed URLs to watch URLs.

Can be used from a shell like
$ ./converter.py -h
$ python3 converter.py "https://www.youtube.com/embed/FjHGZj2IjBk?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0"
$ cat urls.txt > xargs python3 converter.py

or from Python
>>> from converter import convert_to_watch_url
"""

import argparse
import re


def convert_to_watch_url(url: str) -> str:
    """Converts youtube embed-url to watch-url

    >>> convert_to_watch_url("https://www.youtube.com/embed/FjHGZj2IjBk?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0")
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjHGZj2IjBk'

    """
    pattern = r"^.*/embed/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\?controls.*$"
    repl = r"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\1"
    return re.sub(pattern, repl, url)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Small script to convert URLs")
    parser.add_argument("URL", dest="urls", nargs="*", help="URL(s) to convert")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    for url in args.urls:
        print(convert_to_watch_url(url))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and if you want to keep your tests (but my example is also already testable with `doctest`), I'd use pytest and would have the test separate:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.parametrize("embed, watch", [
    ("https://www.youtube.com/embed/NL5ZuWmrisA?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NL5ZuWmrisA")
    ("https://www.youtube.com/embed/gnZImHvA0ME?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnZImHvA0ME")
    ("https://www.youtube.com/embed/FjHGZj2IjBk?controls=2&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&cc_load_policy=0&autoplay=0", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjHGZj2IjBk")
])
def test_convert_watch_url_on_correct_urls():
    assert convert_to_watch_url(embed) == watch
```

(which either needs to import the function or be in the same file).